# What is the most common approach for microservices to access data managed by other micro services?

Tags: architecture, microservices

I am exploring using a microservice architecture. Among others, this would include three services, an Orders Service, a Products Service, and a Fulfillment Service.

Let's say the Fulfillment Service needs information about an order. What would be the more common and most accepted method for Fulfillment Service to access the order information?

1. Fulfillment Service requests order data directly from Order Service via HTTP.
2. Both Fulfillment Service and Order Service track copies of order data in their own databases. When orders are created, updated, or canceled, a message would be published which both services would listen for and handle.

   1. This might result in higher fault tolerance: if Order Service goes down, the Fulfillment Service can continue operating independently via its own copy of data.
   2. I suppose with this approach, you'd want to avoid allowing Fulfillment Service to modify product (each microservice would be the source of truth for its particular data).
3. Another approach.

Some criteria:

1. Avoid anti-patterns.
2. Minimize coupling.
3. Minimize complexity.

Comment: In order to answer the question "what is the most common approach," we would have to ask all of the companies who use micro services that talk to each other how they do it, and create a histogram of the techniques used.  That's a pretty tall order.

Comment: In order to answer the question "what is the most accepted method," you would additionally have to ask those companies why they made the choice they did.

Comment: I'm just looking for what's the generally more accepted approach. I don't think we would have to ask every company out there. For example, if solution #1 is often more frowned upon in the general community, then that might leave us with solution #2. I just want to know peoples' general experience and gather insights. Not looking for a brick wall here.

Comment: Your question would be a better one if you stated some criteria.  In the absence of criteria, any technique will do.

Comment: I've asked plenty of questions like this one with good responses, though I've added criteria as you insist.

Comment: I recently joined a project where approach 1 is used. It doesn't make sense. I keep asking why we use microservices. Noone knows. The original developers are long gone. Boundaries are wrong resulting in many cross service requests. When this scales up it's gonna be a performance nightmare, which is kinda ironic because performance is probably one of the reasons the original developers decided to use microservices. Before deciding which approach to use, ask yourself: What problems do I hope to solve with microservices and are there perhaps other solutions with less complexity.

Comment: Good call, and thank you for the wisdom from your experience. That’s true — I could definitely do this auth one database, and microservices may be overkill. Right now it’s more an opportunity to learn microservices than an actual need. I’ll refactor in a branch and see how it feels.

Comment: Take a step back and remember why you're using microservices in the first place. Why are you?

Comment: I believe (but I'm not sure) the idea with microservices is that they're basically separate applications (which can call into each other). So they should be split along business lines. You don't have a *products* service, you have a *catalog* service which knows which products are in stock now. But it doesn't have to know about discontinued products! And the ordering service needs to know what was ordered, even if the catalog changed since then. And the fulfillment service needs to know what is actually being shipped, even if it's not in the order. There are less links than you think!

Answer (score 2):

Both are viable. They have their tradeoffs.

First one is easier, but if Order service is down, so is Fullfilment service. It also becomes a problem with overall stability. If a service depends on 3 other services, and those have stability of 99.5%, then the service itself would have 0.995^3 = 0.985 = 98.5% . This might be unacceptable. And when you have dozens of services with many instances, these numbers quickly add up.

Second is more difficult, but Fullfilment service can work even when Order service is down. It also allows the Fullfilment service to store the data in a way that is easy for it to consume. This might not be true for whatever API the other services provide for it.

Third option is to use 'delayed' creation. In this scenario, the Fullfilment service tracks the state of it's request in persistent storage and starts it in 'is being fullfilled' state. Then, it sends asynchronous message to Order service, which Order service will process when it is up and ready. Once it is done, it will send response back to Fullfilment service, which will continue in the processing. This is different form of complication than keeping copy of the data, as you need to keep track of fullfilment state and revert it if something goes wrong (eg. with saga). And it requires client of Fullfilment service to know that it's request can be in 'to be finished' state. But it gives you advantage of high stability and no need to keep duplicate data.

Comment: Thank you for a reasonable answer. I think this helps reinforce that the second option would probably be most suitable for my scenario.